# Is $f:\mathbb{P}(A)\to\mathbb{P}(B)$, $f(C)=C\cap B$ injective or surjective?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

[image]

[image]

Question: Is f injective, surjective and bijective?

How do I start?

Comment: You start by reading the definitions of injective and surjective one more time. Then you make a small example for yourself, like $A = \{1, 2, 3\}$ and $B = \{1, 2\}$, and write what $f$ does to each one of the 8 elements of $P(A)$, so that you can 1) perhaps disprove one or both if you're lucky, and 2) get a better intuition for how $f$ works and how the definitions of injective and surjective work in this particular context.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{P}$ what is $C$ ? Describe your notations!

Comment: @Alfha $\Bbb P$ is completely standard notation for the power set operator. And once we have established the domain of $f$, it's obvious that the $C$ in $f(C)$ is an element of said domain, in particular since it's the sentence defining $f$ in the first place. Yes, your concerns do have some merit, but no, I don't think that that's the most important thing to spend energy on this time.

Answer (score 1):

It is not injective,

Note that: $f( \varnothing) = \varnothing $

and $B$ is properly contained in $A$ , so **we'll be able to find at least one nonempty subset of** $A$ **not in** $\mathbb{P}(B)$ say $'k'$ such that

**image of** $k$ **is also** $\varnothing$. (Verify it by yourself)!

Thus we always have more that one elements of domain mapped to $\varnothing$.

As $f$ is not injective so is not bijective, but the map $f$ is surjection as every member of $\mathbb{P}(B)$ is in $\mathbb{P}(A)$.
Edited $\rightarrow$
Note that: NOT EVERY SUBSET OF $A$ HAS IMAGE $\varnothing$ !

Answer (score 0):

The only question not completely obvious is injectivity. Here's a hint:

For any $C\subset A$, $\quad C=(C\cap B)\cup(C\smallsetminus B)$.

Comment: I'd personally say that injectivity is more obvious than surjectivity. Just goes to show, "obvious" is not an objective property of propositions.

Comment: What's not obvious, in my opinion, is how to formalise it for a beginner. For surjectivity, a moment's thinking yields a  solution to the equation in $X$ $f(C)=C'$ for any $C'\subset B$

Comment: You're right. "Never injective" might be a bit more troublesome. I was thinking about "Not always injective", which is definitely the most obvious property here.